# Appendix title on a new line

Tags: sectioning, titles, appendices

I am trying to modify the appearance of the Appendices in my thesis work.
I am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{appendices}
\section{Quantum Mechanics representations}
...
\section{Useful relations}
...
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

But I get something like:

Appendix A     Quantum Mechanics representations

...

Appendix B     Useful relations

...

Instead of this, I would like the titles of the sections to be on a new line, e.g.

Appendix A

Quantum Mechanics representations

...

Appendix B

Useful relations

...

Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the `titlesec` package and change the way sections are typeset when starting your appendices through the command

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\appendixname\enspace\thesection}{.5em}{}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just for the example

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{appendices}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\appendixname\enspace\thesection}{.5em}{}

\section{Quantum Mechanics representations}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Useful relations}
\lipsum[1]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

You can even add these lines in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendices{%
  \titleformat{\section}[display]%
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\appendixname\enspace\thesection}{.5em}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

to avoid using `\titleformat` inside the document.

The following MWE produces the same result:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just for the example

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendices{%
  \titleformat{\section}[display]%
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\appendixname\enspace\thesection}{.5em}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{appendices}

\section{Quantum Mechanics representations}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Useful relations}
\lipsum[1]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```